# do i need to install ACE driver on the production environment?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, ms-jet-ace, vba

So I'm getting this error that ACE OleDb is not registered on my local machine. As far as I'm aware, it is an installable driver. Do i need to install this on my target machine assuming it doesn't have it? BTW it's an Excel import.

Comment: Yes you need to install it on production too.

Comment: Is this a good idea? I suppose it is. How does one package it to install as one with the program i.e: DirectX? @mybirthname